# can't acquire python output

Tags: java, python, sleep

My python code gives a print in java in a while true loop but doesn't print if i put in a sleep, even after the duration of the sleep there is no output in java

```
print 33
import time

while True:
    i = 0
    time.sleep(0.01)
    j = 0
    print 1
```

this is the python code.  I run this from a java code

```
public class DistanceHandler extends Thread
{
    private Process p;
    private ProcessBuilder pb;
    private BufferedReader bfr;

    public DistanceHandler()
    {
        try{
            /*pb = new ProcessBuilder("python", "/home/pi/Distance.py");
            pb.redirectErrorStream(true);
            pb.
            p = pb.start();
            bfr = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));*/
            p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("sudo python /home/pi/test.py -u");
            bfr = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
        } catch (Exception e)  {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }

    public void run(){
        System.out.println("Start read");
        if(p != null) {
            System.out.println("P alive: " + p.isAlive());

            int line = 0;
            try {
                while ((line = bfr.read()) != -1) {
                //display each output line form python script
                   System.out.println((char)line);
                   if(line < 10){
                       System.out.println("Pop that Ballooon ");
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e);
            }
        }
    }    
}
```

Comment: Adding [`sys.stdout.flush()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/io.html#io.IOBase.flush) after the print statement doesn't help, either?

Comment: Thanks, this fixed it

Comment: As for an explanation: The output stream is buffered, i.e. `print` only causes actual output when the buffer is full or when the stream is explicitly flushed. For small pieces of output, your data never leaves the python process, it stays in the stream buffer. File under *the usual problem with streams*

Comment: But why does it work when you dont sleep?

Comment: It also works with the sleep, but it takes a lot longer. You get output the first time the buffer is full. Without the sleep, you are filling the buffer very quickly. With the sleep, filling the buffer takes a lot more time.

Comment: @dhke, if that's the answer, please post it as an answer :-)

Answer (score 1):

This is a common problem. Python (and C, for the matter) streams are [buffered](https://docs.python.org/2/library/io.html#io.DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE).

In your case, this means that a `print` does not necessary cause immediate output, but rather fills the output buffer of the stream.

The Java side of the program will only receive data once after the buffer is full (and then the complete buffer, which is exactly what the buffer is for: avoiding system calls for small scale IO). Now, since the default buffer size is typically 8,192 bytes and assuming the `print 1` writes 2 bytes (`'1\n'`) for every loop, it would take over 40s for the buffer to fill. Thus it might look like the Java program is getting no input, while in fact we are simply waiting for the output buffer on the Python side to fill.

If you remove the `sleep()` you fill the buffer as fast as possible causing an almost immediate write.

You can force the stream to flush the buffer to avoid this problem:

```
while True:
    i = 0
    time.sleep(0.01)
    j = 0
    print 1
    sys.stdout.flush()
```